# MSChart Doesn't Fill Entire Chart Area

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

The MSChart does not fill entire Chart Area, I tried using the example ( [Why Doesn't MSChart Fill Entire Chart Area?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12984852/why-doesnt-mschart-fill-entire-chart-area)) but it did not work

I am using the code below

```
  volumeChart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Interval = 1;// a cada 1 coluna 1 label
            volumeChart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = 45;// Angulo do label
            volumeChart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.LabelStyle.Font = new Font("Tahoma", 8F);
            volumeChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Title = Environment.NewLine + "Qtde";
            volumeChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Title = Environment.NewLine + "Semana / Mês";
            volumeChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;
            volumeChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;
```

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19875180/Chart_Fill.png

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should really try to change the InnerPlotPosition values.

```
// Change to a bigger value if your x and y axis labels are not shown anymore
volumeChart.ChartAreas[0].InnerPlotPosition.X = 0;
volumeChart.ChartAreas[0].InnerPlotPosition.Y = 0;

// Height and width are in percentage (%)
volumeChart.ChartAreas[0].InnerPlotPosition.Height = 100;
volumeChart.ChartAreas[0].InnerPlotPosition.Width = 100;
```